# Enabling or disabling the timer in one of the mdiChild

Tags: vb.net, timer, isenabled

For example I have `frmMenu`, `frmParent` and `frmChild`.

On my `frmChild` I have `tmrChild.enabled = false`. I instantiate `10 frmChild`, so I have `10 frmChild` inside of my `frmParent`. Note that each of `frmChild` has a timer named `tmrChild` inside of them and they are all `enabled = false`.

The name of each `frmChild` form is `frmChild1`, `frmChild2`, `frmChild3` .... `frmChild10`

On my `frmMenu` I have `10 buttons`, each of them corresponds to the `enabled` property of each `frmChild`. So,

`10 buttons on my frmMenu = 10 timer in each of my frmChild`

What I want is when I clicked the `button1` in my frmMenu it will enabled the `timer` in my frmChild1. How do I do that?

I've tried to target the name of `frmChild`, something like this

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
        Dim objForms As Form
        For Each objForms In frmParent.MdiChildren
            If objForms.Text = "frmChild1" Then
                objForms.tmr1.enabled = True
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

It seems that I'm missing something easy on this part of code

```
objForms.tmrChild.enabled = True
```

How do I reference a `timer` on that?

Comment: Instead of `Dim objForms As Form` use `Dim objForms As frmChild`.  This way you can access the variables declared as part of `frmChild` in addition to those declared as part of `Form`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would tend to use a `Dictionary` for this.  Instead of having separate fields for the child forms, just have one field for a `Dictionary(Of Button, fmrChild)`.  You can then add each `Button`/form pair to the `Dictionary`.  When a `Button` is clicked, you get the corresponding form from the `Dictionary` and do as required, e.g.

```
Private childFormsByButton As New Dictionary(Of Button, frmChild)

Private Sub Buttons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click
    Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim frm = childFormsByButton(btn)

    frm.StartTimer()
End Sub
```

Note that the `Handles` clause of that method includes ALL the `Buttons`.

You would, of course, have to write that `StartTimer` method in your child form and, in it, call `Start` on the `Timer`.